# Failed to start php5-fpm.service: Unit php5-fpm.service is masked Laravel Forge

Tags: linux, laravel, php-7, forge

What i'm trying to do is to update update web directory using a server management tool called forge to update web directory (often used to deploy  Laravel Platforms With Nginx, PHP 7.0, MySQL, Postgres, Redis, & More.). For some reason I get this error.

```
Failed to start php5-fpm.service: Unit php5-fpm.service is masked.
```

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Laravel Forge does not use `php5-fpm`. It uses `php7-fpm`.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I know that, but why do this error occur? Forge autmatically installs php7 but fails with this error when Nginx is beeing installed.

Comment: I tested your theory on a fresh VPS but could not simulate the same issue. Can you advise as to what button's you're clicking and such? Also, you can open the `nginx.conf` file and you can see what the `fpm socket` it's using. Then you can change that socket to be the path to the php7 socket.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy basically there is an error occuring, but according to Taylor this error is fine. Forge tries to restart both PHP 7 and PHP 5. There is no way to fix it as far as I know, but you need real existing domains for this to work. Thank you very much for taking your time.